# Create patch for one file with Magit

Tags: magit, git

With command line git you can use `git format-patch [commit_hash] [file]` to generate a patch for a single file. Is there a way to generate a patch in magit for only a single file? I tried marking the files like I would when staging multiple files, but it still created a patch for the whole commit.

Comment: No, `magit-format-patch` doesn't support that, and this isn't an option that you can simply define with `magit-define-popup-option`. I think it's a feature worth proposing on magit's issue tracker.

Comment: It is a pretty simple `start-process` -- at the very least, someone here could create an interactive function that would gather the commit-sha and filename and plug it into the command-line passed to `start-process`.

Comment: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magit supports this now. In the patch popup press <kbd>= F</kbd> and then type the name of the file (with completion). You can also input multiple files, separated by comas.